# How do I test managed files upload through configuration?

Tags: 9, testing

I have a configuration form in Drupal9 which `extend ConfigFormBase` that I need to pass through Behat test.
To simplify the form, I have only one managed_file fields.

```php
$form['card_logo_fid'] = [
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_validators' => ['file_validate_extensions' => ['png gif jpg jpeg']],
  '#default_value' => isset($companyDataConfig['card_logo_fid']) ? $companyDataConfig['card_logo_fid'] : '',
  '#upload_location' => AggregatedContactSettingsForm::UPLOAD_LOCATION,
];
```

What solution do I have to explicitly upload an image in this field using Behat?
Please remember that since it's a configuration form I cannot use the node creation approach which looks like the following.

```
| field_name |
| value      |
```

Comment: Are you using a Behat integration module or project specifically for Drupal?

Comment: This answer won't help you at all in the short term, but I have personally dropped all Behat testing, in favor of Cypress testing (Cypress.io), which I have found much, much easier and better to work with. Something to check out for the future. Sorry I can't help on your current issue though.

Comment: I use `"behat/behat": "3.8.0", within Drupal (https://github.com/Behat/Behat), and no I cannot ditch behat for another testing framework.